# Ruby gem for better/real code coverage (test test case multiple times)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, code-coverage

Roughly 6 years ago I have seen a presentation about a Gem that would improve your tests (in this case rspec specs).

The gem would re-run all your specs multiple times (n+1 if I remember correctly) and change variable values in the background. Then it would expect that the tests still succeed (or fail, depending on the change) in case the result is different, the test is considered "to be improved" as you can have unexpected results.

The whole idea of the gem was to prove that your 100% code coverage, was not a real 100% code coverage. Though sadly I forgot the name of the gem, and I am hoping you maybe know the gem I am asking about.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the gem you are looking for is `mutant`. It is manipulating parts of the code to check if the specs are covering edge cases.

Check out the [Github Repository](https://github.com/mbj/mutant)